# How can I get exatcly one row from database query for every course loop

Tags: jmeter

I creating script which let me to get values from database.
Now, when I'm executing query oracle returning me too many values.

My query looks like that : `select * FROM OFFERS`

[image]

I'm getting:

```
OFFER_NR_#=101042
OFFER_NR_1=0001G000210
OFFER_NR_10=0001G000411
```

and many many more...

[image]

I want to take exactly one value e.g. OFFER_NR and use it in request

```
------- request SEARCH_OFFER ${OFFER_NR}             = 101042
```

During next course loop I want to take another value as variable

```
------- request SEARCH_OFFER ${OFFER_NR}             =  0001G000210
```

It's just like using CSV FILE CONFIGURATION, which can give me exactly each next row for every thread group iteration, but I don't know how can I do this the same using jdbc request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 You need to use [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) configured as follows:

- Input Variable Prefix: OFFER_NR
- Output Variable Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `CURRENT_OFFER`
- Check `Add "_" before number" box

  2. Place your 2nd request under the ForEach Contoller
  3. Refer each subsequent OFFER_NR as `${CURRENT_OFFER}` where required

See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) guide for more detailed explanation of your and other situations